# Blender 2.83, was sculpting and suddenly my smoothing brush stopped working

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I have no idea what happened, but when I try a stroke, a red line appears which hadn't appeared before and I'm still new to 2.8 so i have no idea what brush settings could have caused this.

This only affects the smooth brush.

Answer (score 0):

In the Properties sidebar, go to *Stroke > Stabilize Stroke* and turn it off.

*Stabilize Stroke* basically drags the "actual" brush behind your cursor when sculpting. This results in a red line indicating the distance the actual brush is from the cursor. I do believe this red line is resulting from *Stabilize Stroke*.

Answer (score 0):

My brush completely disappeared inexplicably. While I'm not sure what I pressed, I found a solution:
Go to the Properties sidebar and in the Tool section at the top, look for the Stroke chevron. It'll be under Advanced and Texture, a bit above Dyntopo. Fiddle around with the Stroke Method feature and it may fix it for you. My cursor was completely absent when the Stroke Feature was set to curve.